# Doctrine2 after entity update still generate old database table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Im learning doctrine2. Problem is: I have just updated my entity class. Old version of entity consisted of $id, $name and $username fields. After this update below, I run command doctrine:generate:entities Acme, doctrine:update:schema and etc., but result is still old table with only 3 fields. It looks like old meta-data is saved somewhere. Can someone provide me with information what Im doing wrong ? And why I get old database table instead of new one ? And even how to solve my problem ?

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User implements UserInterface, EquatableInterface
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="roles", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $roles;

    /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="apikey", type="array")
     */
    private $apiKey;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", length=10)
     */
    private $salt;

    function __construct($apiKey, $id, $password ,$roles , $salt, $username)
    {
        $this->apiKey = $apiKey;
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->roles = $roles;
        $this->salt = $salt;
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    /**
     * The equality comparison should neither be done by referential equality
     * nor by comparing identities (i.e. getId() === getId()).
     *
     * However, you do not need to compare every attribute, but only those that
     * are relevant for assessing whether re-authentication is required.
     *
     * Also implementation should consider that $user instance may implement
     * the extended user interface `AdvancedUserInterface`.
     *
     * @param UserInterface $user
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user)
    {

        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->password !== $user->getPassword()) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->salt !== $user->getSalt()) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->username !== $user->getUsername()) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }



    /**
     * Returns the roles granted to the user.
     *
     * <code>
     * public function getRoles()
     * {
     *     return array('ROLE_USER');
     * }
     * </code>
     *
     * Alternatively, the roles might be stored on a ``roles`` property,
     * and populated in any number of different ways when the user object
     * is created.
     *
     * @return Role[] The user roles
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the password used to authenticate the user.
     *
     * This should be the encoded password. On authentication, a plain-text
     * password will be salted, encoded, and then compared to this value.
     *
     * @return string The password
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the salt that was originally used to encode the password.
     *
     * This can return null if the password was not encoded using a salt.
     *
     * @return string|null The salt
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the username used to authenticate the user.
     *
     * @return string The username
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getApiKey()
    {
        return $this->apiKey;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $apiKey
     */
    public function setApiKey($apiKey)
    {
        $this->apiKey = $apiKey;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }


    /**
     * Removes sensitive data from the user.
     *
     * This is important if, at any given point, sensitive information like
     * the plain-text password is stored on this object.
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // TODO: Implement eraseCredentials() method.
    }
}
```

Comment: `doctrine:generate:entities` will read the DB structure and generate entities from the information. What exactly do you run?

Comment: doctrine:schema:create, doctrine:schema:update. I delete old table and database then create new and so on. But result is always same. I did doctrine:generate:entities with success and still nothing new. Well to be more precise I deleted old database and then try all variations to create new table.

Comment: Any useful hints in php_errors.log?

Comment: No useful hints. In my opinion there is some kind of file somewhere from which doctrine gets old meta-data. I can't find it. Tried all doctrine cache delete commands.

Answer (score 2):

If the old metadata is saved You have to clear cache

```
doctrine:cache:clear-metadata         Clears all metadata cache for an entity manager
  doctrine:cache:clear-query            Clears all query cache for an entity manager
  doctrine:cache:clear-result           Clears result cache for an entity manager
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you did not executed the update command correctly.

You'll need to force the changes:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Or dump the SQL and execute it manually:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

Comment: I know it sounds strange and funny but it doesnt work. After force update and sql dump i get old sql query. I probably broke something that i cant understand atm.