# Updating same query repeatedly in database generation

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have generated entities from a (MySQL) database, then created a new (zf2) project with a blank database by running the following statements:

```
vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create
vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:update --force
vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:validate-schema
```

Unfortunately the update statement keeps updating the same statement:

```
ALTER TABLE rollen CHANGE name name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL;
```

and the validation fails. The DB shows the correct column. The Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Comparator shows a different precision (not yet quite sure what that is supposed to be) of the corresponding column.

[Some](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/issues/103) related [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355126/doctrine2-after-entity-update-still-generate-old-database-table) did not seem to fit or work.

Comment: I [removed tags from the title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) and clarified it, and tweaked the body. Also pothole inlined the related links for smoothness.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the corresponding diffColumn function in Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Comparator, showed me that auto-increment set in the meta-data schema (see following annotation):

```
@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
```

the precision part seems to be part of this strategy (although I still don't understand this, since a auto-increment id is rather an in than decimal, see http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#column)